# I have the following table and want to turn the rows into different columns

Tags: sql-server-2005

```
ID    Code      Date
1     3101       10/2/2010
1     3101       15/2/2010
2     3101       18/2/2010
2     3101       25/4/2010
2     3101       21/4/2010
```

into the following

```
ID   Date1      Date2      Date3       Date4      Date5
 1   10/2/2010  15/2/2010  
 2   18/2/2010  25/4/2010  21/4/2010
```

Comment: Just noticed, what's posted now would *not* be solved by a simple pivot query. It looks like you want one row per Id, and one column for every distinct date for that Id (with the dates "sorted ascending" across columns), resulting with as many columns as there are the most dates for any given Id (i.e. in your example, you know there will be up to 5 dates per Id) -- OR, you have a hard-and-fast cap of displaying no more than five dates per Id?

Comment: I guess my question is, how many Date columns do you need, and what determines the contenst of those columns in each row?

Comment: Exactly what I need - I tried using cursor but my knowledge let me down as still learning

Comment: I am hoping it is no more than 10  and if I explain what i am trying to do it may help

we have rows and rows of coded data with a date for each time that code is used for each ID and we want to show each ID with there relevant dates (we have 2 codes 3101 is a start and 1101 isand endand we aregoing to calculated the number of days between each start and end then add them up to give us a totalfor each ID)

Comment: some ids can have more than 1 start and end

Comment: Could you mark the question as answered?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(SQL.90).aspx) for this. Example below:

```
CREATE TABLE #Data
(
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    Code INT NOT NULL,
    [Date] VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
)
INSERT INTO #Data VALUES(1, 3101, '10-2-2010')
INSERT INTO #Data VALUES(1, 3101, '15-2-2010')
INSERT INTO #Data VALUES(2, 3101, '18-2-2010')
INSERT INTO #Data VALUES(2, 3101, '25-4-2010')
INSERT INTO #Data VALUES(2, 3101, '21-4-2010')

SELECT ID, [1] AS Date1, [2] AS Date2, [3] AS Date3, [4] AS Date4
FROM
(SELECT ID, [Date], ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) [RowNum]
 FROM #Data) AS p
PIVOT (Max([Date]) FOR [RowNum] IN ([1],[2],[3],[4])) AS pvt
```

Suppose you need more dates, it is just a matter of adding more pivot rows.

Comment: SELECT ID,  [Date1],[Date2],[Date3],[Date4]
 FROM
  (SELECT ID, Date 
   FROM #tempAMS)
    p PIVOT (Max(Date)FOR Date IN ([Date1],[Date2],[Date3],[Date4]))
AS pvt

This is my attempt at a pivotand itdoesnt seemto work - Icant get the dates into the relevant columns

Comment: I was trying originally to use a cursor as I aslo will have other codes to go into other date columns so I can calculate the numberof days paused per id but that wouldnt do it for me either - I am new to TSQL and have only been using it a couple of months

Comment: I'm also trying to get this to work but it seems I'm not that good in pivoting data after all.. I'll keep trying..

Comment: @Ronald: This is a very useful method of pivoting. Great use of row_number! +1

Comment: Wonderful I will go and transfer this into my database Thanks

Comment: You're welcome :) Could you please mark the question as answered?